# How is this reduce operation mutating my original array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to reduce the `items` array so that it includes a single element for "apple" with an updated quantity. The code below returns the correct reduced array, but it also mutating the original `items` array and I don't understand why.

```js
const items = [
    {name: "apples", qty: 1},
    {name: "bananas", qty: 1},
    {name: "apples", qty: 3}
];

const reducedItems = items.reduce(function(newArray, currentItem) {
    const indexForCurrentItem = newArray.findIndex(
        ({name}) => name === currentItem.name
    );
    // if current item is not in newArray, add it
    // but if it is already in newArray, update its quantity property there
    indexForCurrentItem === -1
        ? newArray.push(currentItem)
        : newArray[indexForCurrentItem].qty += currentItem.qty;
    return newArray;
}, []);

console.log(reducedItems);
console.log(items);

// reducedItems is correct: [{name: "apples", qty: 4}, {name: "bananas", qty: 1}]

// but items is now:
//  [
//      {name: "apples", qty: 4},
//      {name: "bananas", qty: 1},
//      {name: "apples", qty: 1}
//  ]
```

Comment: One solution could be to make a shallow copy of your object before you push it into your array `function(newArray, {...currentItem})`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding objects from `items` into `newArray` when you call `newArray.push(currentItem)`. `newArray` will hold the same objects (with the same reference) as in `items`. When you later call `newArray[indexForCurrentItem].qty += currentItem.qty` you update the object that is present in both arrays.

A simple fix would be to add copies of objects to the new array.

```
newArray.push(Object.assign({}, currentItem))
```

With this change `newArray` will hold (shallow) copies of objects. If you change the copy the original in `items` will be unaffected.